# How to deal with matrix not having an inverse in ordinary least squares?

Tags: least-squares

I have a problem for which I am trying to apply least squares to a set of data by solving $$Y=\beta X$$ where Y is a vector of size $n$ and X is a matrix of size $n\times p$. From my understanding the solution to OLS is $\hat{\beta} =(X^TX)^{-1} X^TY$.
My issue is that my matrix for $(X^TX)$ is singular and so has no inverse.
Below are my matrix and vector for X and Y

`X = 
0 1 -210.685 16487.4
0 1 -148.918 8204.42
0 1 -184.327 12602.8
0 1 -156.044 9014.04
0 1 -180.295 12054.6`

`Y =
19.631
33.707
26.5648
49.4853
33.6831`

Comment: You matrix is singular solely because of the supererogatory column of zeros.  Remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the zero column, i.e. the first one. When you do, at least you'll have a solution because $X^TX$ become nonsingular. In its current form the first column can be obtained via multiplying any of the other columns by $0$, which means linear dependence and singularity. You might additionally consider feature scaling and regularization, which is not directly related to the singularity issue at hand.